# Unable to access Controller variable in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controllers

I am playing with a simple app that does a Facebook login using omniauth-facebook. This is for learning purposes. I am able to get the login to work and I get the callback. After this I am trying to display the user's name, email in the show.html.erb but for some reason it always prints blank. HEre is what I am doing in the controller:

```
def create
  @c_user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  @c_name = @c_user.name
  @c_email = @c_user.email
  @c_website = @c_user.website
  logger.debug("current user has name  #{@c_user.name}")
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in as #{@c_name} #{@c_email}!"
 end
```

This function prints the correct value for user name and email and the notice is also correctly sent to the show view. However in the show.html.erb, blank values are printed.

```
HEre is my show.html.erb:

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
 <strong>Name:</strong>
 <%= puts @c_name, @temp_var %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Email:</strong>
<%= @c_email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Website:</strong>
  <%= @c_website %>
</p>

<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're rendering `show.html.erb` from your `root_url`.  Instead of doing that, you could have just rendered the `show` action and your view would have populated correctly.

The reason your variables are not available in the view is because you are doing a redirect.  When you do a redirect none of the instance variables are available in the redirected url.

So, instead of redirecting, you could just render the `show` action as follows:

```
def create
  @c_user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  @c_name = @c_user.name
  @c_email = @c_user.email
  @c_website = @c_user.website
  logger.debug("current user has name  #{@c_user.name}")

  flash[:notice] = "Signed in as #{@c_name} #{@c_email}!"
  render :show 
end
```

Comment: One thing I did not understand is why the redirect resets everything.. how do I understand the difference between the show and the redirect? What are the reasons for using the redirect in general?

Comment: @user3079275, please have a read on this: https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155